# Need advice on how to wire a switch outlet combo with two hot wires

Tags: electrical

So my situation is that I have a switch which controls an outlet. I want to wire in a switch outlet combo to still control that outlet with the switch, but also have constant power to the outlet on the combo receptacle. The issue is that there are only to hot wires in the box. The grounds are wire nutted together, one hot line is independent, and the other is wire nutted to two other hot lines. I have tried every possible combination that I can think of. The switch still works as before but I cannot get power to the outlet on the combo receptacle. How can I wire this so I can get the desired outcome?

[image: picture of inside of switch box]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Do *not* use trial and error and all combinations to solve wiring problems.  Do you still know how it was originally wired?  It appears power comes to this box and goes to the plug from there, and if that's the case, you have a line wire and a neutral present and it's possible to do what you want.    If power goes to the plug first, unfortunately your plan won't work out, so you need a bit more information.

Comment: @user263983 Judging from the presence and wires in those splices it seems likely a neutral is present, although that should be confirmed.

Comment: Are you trying to put a swich/receptacle combo *here at the switch location*?  Or are you trying to have a receptacle not pictured that is controlled by this switch, have 1 socket switched 1 socket always-hot?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to wire the switch outlet receptacle at this location. The power is fed here first, as there is no power to the outlet. Both hot wires have power, as I have tested the terminals with a voltmeter

Comment: This room, the hallway, and another bedroom are on the same circuit breaker if that helps

Comment: Since there appears to be a bundle of whites nutted together in the background, those should be the neutrals. The hots are brown, so you should have conduit in the walls which makes adding wires easy (though you shouldn't need to), _but_ it appears that one of those wires disappears into a sheath toward the back of the box... Where in the world are you? Also, **without detaching anything**, can you pull all the wires out of the box & take another pic (assuming that this setup is the original and working).

Comment: @KH my comment has been mad before the OP posted the picture. I did not try to judge anybody or anything, just giving the information or solution, based on posted information. My opinion the site is for technical information.

Comment: I've never seen such groovy cables.   Hot is a medium taupe and neutral is a deep cream?  Is that it?  I can hardly tell black from white when it's aged and dirty, how do you work with this???

Comment: Do all of:  1) Clarify (edit) your question.    You want a new combo at "this switch location", to be [switched or unswitched] and the "existing remote outlet" to [remain switched or become unswitched].   2) Post pictures of the combo switch you bought, clearly showing both sides.  3) Post pictures of the inside of the remote outlet clearly showing the wiring 4) Pull out the wires of this box, without undoing anything, and post a picture showing what's connected to what 5) Tell us how these subtle skin tones are used to identify wires in your location.  The barely darker one is hot?

Comment: @user263983  No worries.  The word "judging" in the sentence as I used it means I'm using *my* judgement of the picture to hypothesize the presence of a neutral.  Did not mean to imply you were being judgemental =).  Didn't know you hadn't seen the picture though.

Answer (score 2):

Your description and comments are a little confusing, and your picture lacks detail, but I'll take a general swing at this. I think you want to swap this switch for a Leviton style [switch/receptacle combo](https://www.leviton.com/sites/REST/controller/LCDownloadController/download/RESI-52xx-Instruction-Sheet-EnFrSp.pdf?docid=1471850138996) with the new switch controlling the existing receptacle(s).

Add white wire from the existing nutted white wires to the silver screw on the new device.

It looks like the wire from the top of the switch goes unspliced directly into a cable with two insulated conductors, if your existing receptacle is not a split duplex that cable normally would be a cable to the receptacle.

If you want the switch to control only the existing wall receptacle, and the half of the combo to stay hot then attach that top wire to the gold screw and the wire from the bottom of the switch to one of the black screws. There should be two black screws, it doesn't matter which one since you should be able to see they are connected together.

If you want the switch to control both the receptacle at the switch and the existing then attach the top wire to one of the black screws, and the bottom wire to the gold screw.

Add a bare wire to the ground screw.